# Artifactory getStats always returns null object

Tags: docker, artifactory, rest

I am trying to get the download statistics of a docker image we host on our own artifactory server in a groovy plugin on the server.
So far it looks like the `manifest.json` file has the statistics I am looking for.

`repositories.getStats(RepoPath)` should return a `StatsInfo` object which has `getDownloadCount()`.

However, no matter what I pass to `repositories.getStats()` it always returns a `null` object.

I've tried:

- docker-local
- docker-local/ai
- docker-local/ai/latest
- docker-local/ai/latest/manifest.json

But still `repositories.getStats()` return a null object.

I would expect the following to work:

```
def stats = repositories.getStats(RepoPathFactory.create('docker-local','ai/latest/manifest.json'))
def dlCount = stats.getDownloadCount()
```

But it keeps returning the error:

`"Cannot invoke method getDownloadCount() on null object"`

Calling `?stats` on the `manifest.json` through the REST API works and it returns a json formatted string with the download statistics. Ex:

`my-artifactory-server.io/api/storage/docker-local/ai/latest/manifest.json?stats`

```
  "uri" : "my-artifactory-server.io/api/storage/docker-local/ai/latest/manifest.json",

  "downloadCount" : 10,

  "lastDownloaded" : 1593160404880,

  "lastDownloadedBy" : "Peter Griffin",

  "remoteDownloadCount" : 0,

  "remoteLastDownloaded" : 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you tried looks ok, may be you need to enforce the `stats` object has to be `StatsInfo`
Below is my tested and working code which prints the download count of `manifest.json`

```
import org.artifactory.repo.RepoPathFactory
import org.artifactory.fs.StatsInfo

executions {
    getDockerStats() {
        def statsInfo = (StatsInfo) repositories.getStats(RepoPathFactory.create("docker-local","hello-world/latest/manifest.json"))
        log.info("stats download count : ${statsInfo.getDownloadCount()}")
    }
}
```

and in the logs
`[getDockerStats:12             ] [http-nio-8081-exec-5] - stats download count : 2`